# ObjectA inside ListA, ListA inside ObjectB, ObjectB inside ListC

Tags: javascript, arrays, sockets, websocket

I'm making a socket.io game and storing the bullet data is becoming a problem for me. How do I put a bullet object inside of a list of bullet object, that is inside of an object, that is inside of a list of all the main objects.

Server Code:

```
var Player = function(id) {
   var self = {
   canshot: false,
   bullets: []
   }
}
socket.on('shoot', function(data){
   if(player.canshot){
      console.log("FIre")
      player.canshot = false
      player.bullets.push({
        xV:data.xVel,
        yV:data.yVel,
        x:data.x,
        y:data.y
      });
      time = 1000/player.fireRate
      setTimeout(() => {
         player.canshot = true;
      }, time);
    }
 });
//Sends data in loop
   bullets:player.bullets,
   canshot:player.canshot
```

Client Code:

```
///When client recieves server info,

**ctx.fillText(player[i].bullets[data[i].bullets.length],10,20)**
```

If you want to see all the code, you can see it here: https://repl.it/@Helixable/FireAway

Comment: i would say bad design. better use a different data structure better suited . For example have a list of players and a list of bullets or sth along these lins

Comment: @NikosM. How would I see what bullet is connected to what player?

Comment: you can have a mapping data structure between player id and bullet id or sth alogn these lines

Comment: @NikosM. I don't have much experience with Js so I don't know what you mean by a mapping data structure.

Comment: I mean a way to avoid all this nesting. A mappinfg data structure is simply an object which maps bullet ids to player ids eg `{'bullet1':'player1','bullet2':'player2'}` and so on. it is simply a way to flatten all this nesting. or sth along these lines

Comment: For example I would suggest create another `Class Bullet` along with Player class, now a player.bullets will have references to Bullet instances. Also Bullet.player will have reference to player instance, then you can handle it better since each bullet knows which player it belongs too and can interchange information. This double linking I think will help you solve the issue

Comment: @NikosM. I'll see.

Comment: also dont use `self` in Player class as you do now. `self` is a global variable, better use `this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the line of reasoning that I expressed in my comments your code can be refactored to sth like the following to help you address this nesting issue:

```
// Player Class
function Player(id)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.canshot = false;
    this.bullets = [];
    this.fireRate = 100; // whatever
|

// Bullet class
function Bullet(player, xV,yV,x,y)
{
    this.player = player;
    this.xV = xV;
    this.yV = yV;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

// other code

socket.on('shoot', function(data){
   if(player.canshot){
      console.log("FIre")
      player.canshot = false
      var bullet = new Bullet(player, data.xVel, data.yVel, data.x, data.y);
      player.bullets.push(bullet);
      time = 1000/player.fireRate
      setTimeout(() => {
         player.canshot = true;
      }, time);
    }
 });
```

Now each bullet can be handled on its own since it knows to which player it vbelongs to and you can avoid all this nesting of players and bullets